# Regex extract some specific number from string, tried several methods

Tags: regex, string, perl, extract

I need to extract a specific number from string in variable; for example, `$ex` is having URLs like `"https://www.google.com&r=12345&s=1&t=2"`,  and I need to extract `12345` only. I tried these three regexes but it's not working.

1. This one returning `=12345=1=2`.

   ```perl
   $example = $1 if( $ex=~ s/[^=\d]//g);
   ```
2. This one returning null.

   ```perl
   $example = $1 if($ex=~ m/r\=([\d+])\&/i);
   ```
3. This one returning null.

   ```perl
   $example = $1 if($ex=~ m/r\^=([\d+])\&/i)
   ```

Comment: Re "*This one returning null.*", No, it doesn't set `$example` to undefined; it merely leaves it unchanged.

Comment: @sticky bit, I saw that, but it specifically asks to use URI.pm, which will the correct answer, makes me hesitant to close this as a dup of that. (I'd rather close that as this.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```perl
use URI             qw( );
use URI::QueryParam qw( );

$url = URI->new($url);
my $example = $url->query_param('r');  # Get first `r` arguments.
my @example = $url->query_param('r');  # Get all `r` arguments.
```